# union of locally convergent domains regarding $\zeta(s)=\sum1/n^s$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, analytic-number-theory

The series representation $\sum1/n^s$ of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is known to converge for $\sigma>1$, where $s=\sigma+it$.

In order to show an infinite series is holomorphic, we need to show the series **converges uniformly**.

However, the series $\sum 1/n^s$ doesn't converge uniformly in the domain $\sigma>1$. Intuitively, the closer $s$ is closer to $s=1$ the more quickly it diverges.

To address this, various sources make an argument based on **locally uniform convergence**.

The argument is that the series is uniformly convergent on any $\sigma>a$ where $a>1$. The argument proceeds by saying that the union of all these domains is $\sigma>1$, so the series is uniformly convergent here.

**This is where I am confused.** Surely $\sigma>a$ with $a>1$ means $\sigma>1$ which we agreed at the top is a domain in which the series does not converge uniformly.

**Question:** What am I misunderstanding about the standard argument? Where is my error?

Answer (score 3):

As you said the series converges uniformly on $\Re(s) \ge 1+\epsilon$ (so that it is analytic there, by say Morera's theorem) and only locally uniformly on $\Re(s) >1$ (so that it is analytic there as well).
Analyticity is also immediate from expanding $\zeta(z+s)=\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{-z}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{s^k (-\log n)^k }{k!}$ for $|s|<\Re(z)-1$, using the absolute convergence to change the order of summation, obtaining  $\zeta(z+s)= \sum_{k\ge 0}s^k \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{ n^{-z} (-\log n)^k}{k!}$

Comment: I always favor the power series approach to study the analyticity of functions :D

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that the Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$ converges uniformly for $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$. This is also not how the "easy" arguments go to show that $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic for $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$.

The typical argument begins as you note: for any $a > 1$, the Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$ converges absolutely for $\mathrm{Re} s > a$. It follows that for any compact subset $K$ contained in the halfplane $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$, the Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$ converges uniformly on $K$. Then Morera's theorem applies, showing that the Dirichlet series for $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic in $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$.

Now with slightly more detail. Morera's theorem says that if $f$ is continuous in a nice domain $D$, and if for any triangle $T$ contained in $D$ we have that
$$ \int_T f(z) dz = 0, $$
then $f$ is holomorphic in $D$.

Suppose now that $f_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions that converges uniformly to a function $f$ in every compact subset $K$ of some region $\Omega$. Then  in fact $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$. (Sometimes stated concisely as *locally uniform convergence of holomomorphic functions is holomorphic*). To see this, let $D$ be a closed disk contained in $\Omega$, and let $T$ be any triangle in that disk. As each $f_n$ is holomorphic, we know that
$$ \int_T f_n(z) dz = 0 \quad (\forall n). $$
As $f_n \to f$ uniformly in the closure of $D$, one can show that
$$ \int_T f_n(z) dz \to \int_T f(z) dz $$
and also that $f$ is continuous. Morera's theorem now shows that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$. As this is true for any $D$ in $\Omega$, we find that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks @davidlowryduda - I will take a few hours to read and digest your reply. A first question: does absolute converge imply uniform convergence? This is how I interpret your second paragraph. Is this obvious or something non-trivial?

Comment: @Tariq If a Dirichlet series conveges absolutely at $\sigma + it$, then it converges uniformly for $\mathrm{Re} s > \sigma$. There is a short, direct proof of this that I encourage you to consider if it feels nonobvious. (And ping if this is unclear).

Comment: hi @davidlowryduda - I've spent an hour and a half googling for this theorem but have failed to find an explanation of why absolute convergence implies uniform convergence. I've also looked through my copies of Stopple, Apostle and Abbott and not found it. I'd welcome a pointer / link. To me, absolute convergence implying conditional divergence is "obvious" but implying uniform is not obvious.

Comment: @Tariq: Say $\mathrm{Re} s > \sigma$. Then $$ \left \lvert \sum_{n > M} \frac{a(n)}{n^s} \right \rvert < \sum_{n > M} \frac{\lvert a(n) \rvert}{n^{\sigma}},$$ and for sufficiently large $M$ this is bounded by $\epsilon$ independent of $s$ for any $s$ with $\mathrm{Re} s > \sigma$. Thus the sequence of functions are uniformly Cauchy, and converge uniformly. Note: a stronger statement is also true. If a Dirichlet series converges conditionally at $\sigma + it$, then it converges locally uniformly for $\mathrm{Re} s > \sigma$. This is Theorem 11.11 of Apostol, which you noted before.

Comment: hi @davidlowryduda - I'm still working through your replies. I also found this short proof on the brilliant.org tutorial website ( https://brilliant.org/wiki/uniform-convergence/ ) which suggests a simple application of the Wierstrass M-Test is an easy way to show uniform convergence of the dirichlet series for $\Re(s)>1$ .. and hence holomorphic. This seem deceptively easy - is it wrong?

Comment: @Tariq It is an easy consequence of Cauchy's criterion. More specifically, it's a matter of triangle inequality.

Comment: hi @TravorLZH - thanks but it isn't obvious to me. Can you point me to an elaboration?

Comment: hi @davidlowryduda - my apologies for my continued confusion. That brilliant.org website says, and I quote "Weierstrass M-test implies that ζ(x) is uniformly convergent on [a,∞)". This seems to contradict your very first sentence that the dirichlet series does not converge uniformly. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tariq What I mentioned was just a brief sketch of a derivation for the Weierstrass M test. An elaboration should be available to any textbooks in mathematical analysis.

Comment: @Tariq There is no contradiction. They also introduce $a > 1$, exactly as I do in my answer.

Comment: so I'm really confused ... what's the difference between "doesn't uniformly converge for $\sigma>1$" and "it does for $\sigma>a$ where $a>1$" ?

Comment: @Tariq This is exactly analogous to the following simpler statement. For any $a > 1$, function $1/(x-1)$ is uniformly continuous in the region $x > a$, but it is not uniformly continuous in $x > 1$. The point is the same: one avoids an arbitrarily small neighborhood which contains all the "bad behavior" --- for $\zeta(s)$, that's a neighborhood of the line $\mathrm{Re} s = 1$, for the function $1/(x-1)$, it's a neighborhood around the point $x = 1$.

Comment: hi @davidlowryduda - thanks for persisting with me. If the domain was "closed" $x \geq 1$ then I would understand the point. But of the domain is "open" $x>1$ then any point in that domain has a gap to the problematic "x=1". This is based on my recent understanding of complex derivatives. ... another way of making my point is that we can pick a problematic point $x_0$ which is always $x_0 > a$. I understand if you've had enough of explaining this now! I have bought myself a copy of Remmert's Theory of Complex Functions to see if that helps.

Comment: @Tariq I think it might be helpful to draw attention again to the real function $1/(x-1)$ and how it is uniformly continuous in the region $x > a$ for any $a > 1$, but not in the region $x > 1$. There are no complex derivatives here. There are no problematic points $x_0$ with $x_0 > a > 1$. This is a focused exercise in understanding (real-valued) uniform continuity. If this remains confusing, I think it might also be a good idea to distill another question and ask it one this site.

Comment: thanks @davidlowryduda - I will ask that question on this site - and thank you for helping me zoom into a simpler question which highlights my misunderstanding.